# When sculpting cloth nothing happens, object turns dark

Tags: objects, physics, sculpting

I'm new to Blender and I'm following Blender Guru's tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlrgFS8AMMU at about 11:59).

So far everything has worked according to plan. First I added a cloth physics to the couch cushion with 5 pressure and 0 gravity. Then I tried out the cloth sculpting brush on a flat plane to make sure it works, which it did. I selected my object (couch cushion) and moved to sculpt mode. The object turns dark grey, and sometimes I get a warning that says "object has non-uniform scale, sculpting may be unpredictable." When I use the brush and try the space stroke method or line as the tutorial suggests, nothing happens. I checked my settings to make sure they look the same as they do in the tutorial, and they are.
I have no idea why it is acting up.
Any help would be great, thanks.
[image]

Comment: you need to apply any modifiers that's what solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

"object has non-uniform scale, sculpting may be unpredictable." --> so you need to select the object in object mode and press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then select SCALE.

in this way you reset the scale of the object. It has to be 1:1:1 (check it pressing <kbd>N</kbd> on the viewport and go under Item's tab)